# Run shell and convert image before updating mysql row?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ssh

I run a shell script in my php script.

```
$make_small_thumbnail = shell_exec("convert ".$upload_dir."medium/".$processed_filename.".jpeg -resize 133x75 -background black -gravity center -extent 133x75  ".$upload_dir."thumb/".$processed_filename.".jpeg");
```

Then I have a mysql query right after that

```
$query = "UPDATE etc...";
```

However, it updates the row before the shell completes its image conversion. How can I make sure the image is converted before the update is performed?

Comment: Please contact the vendor of `convert` for detailed usage instructions.

Answer (score 1):

For that you can simply check if the final image exists, something like:

```
while(file_exists(PATH_TO_FILE) != true)
   sleep(1); //wait one second

If file exists run query.
```

Comment: It's a curing the symptoms, not the disease

Answer (score 0):

What does

```
$make_small_thumbnail = shell_exec("convert ".$upload_dir."medium/".$processed_filename.".jpeg -resize 133x75 -background black -gravity center -extent 133x75  ".$upload_dir."thumb/".$processed_filename.".jpeg");
echo $make_small_thumbnail;
echo "<br />\n";
echo 'tests';
```

show? My guess is, although the shell_exec is a command within the same thread, the convert command actually starts a new thread or at least is making php think the command is finished. If this is the case, your sql-insert is being run WHILE your convert-command is being executed. Either change your command so shell_exec waits until convert is done or don't use shell_exec at all and use the imagick library instead to achieve the same result.

Comment: @Stijn I get just <br /> and tests echoed. With a warning from a previous command line which doesn't affect the next.